# Explanation of examples of the Big-O Notation

Tags: limits, asymptotics, computer-science

I have found some interesting exercises on the Internet about O-notation. Many of the examples I found were feasible, but with these two I am not quite sure how to find the solution, so I ask here. The following is to be determined there:

Indicate whether $f=O(g)$, or $f=Ω(g)$ or both, in which case $f=Θ(g)$ applies

In the following I am interested in these two tasks, the solution of which I cannot quite comprehend:

1.) $f(n)=n^{0.1}, \quad g(n) = (log(n))^{10}$,
Solution is $f=Ω(g)$ but why this is the case?

2.) $f(n) = 2^{k\cdot \log(n)}, \quad g(n) = n^k$,
No solution is named here, but I'am interested in a solution

It would be very kind if someone could help me. I have already solved other tasks for O Notation for personal practice, but the two tasks were not solvable for me...

Answer (score 1):

I assume $k>0$.

$$2^{k\log n}=e^{k\log n\log 2}=n^{k\log 2}\le n^k$$ hence $f=O(g)$.

On the other hand, $f=\Omega(g)$ is not possible because

$$cn^{k\log 2}\ge n^k$$ would require $$c\ge n^{k(1-\log2)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have a short question, how did you get from $2^{k\cdot \log(n)}$ to $e^{k\log n\log 2}$ so quickly? Which arithmetic law did you use?

Comment: @P_Gate: what do you know about logarithms and exponents ?

Comment: I know the common logarithmic laws, but I don't see which helps here.EDIT: Ah, but now I see that for example $2^x = \left(\text{e}^{\ln(2)}\right)^x = \text{e}^{\ln(2)\cdot x}$, which helps here. At least for the second task.

Comment: @P_Gate: come on, $2=e^{\log2}$.

Comment: This is definitely helpful!

Comment: This is only half an answer: the other half is showing that $f\ne O(g)$.

Comment: @TonyK: hehe, nobody noticed my big mistake...